# Use X data as X axis points in Excel

Tags: excel, plot

My question regards graph plotting in Excel.

Say you have the following data:

X = [2,4,8,16,32]
Y = [20,40,80,160,320]

Plotting this data into a scatter XY graph, I get the following:

[image]

Is there any way for me to control which points are used in the X axis? I want it to have specifically the points [2,4,8,16,32] and not the ones that are assigned automatically by Excel?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You'll need Excel to interpret the x-axis values as text, but by definition it cannot do this for a Scatter Chart. I would change your Chart Type to a Line Chart and format it appropriately.